# Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed on button clicked event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I see that there are many questions regarding this error however I can't understand what's happening in my specific scenario. I'm not entirely sure, becuse I've built this application mostly using `jQuery Ajax` calls but I think I wasn't getting this error before, but that's not 100% certain.

However, my setup is this - I have a `Default.aspx` page where I just added this button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Runat=server Text="Login" OnClick="Login_Click"></asp:Button><br>
```

and in my code behind I have:

```
    protected void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

I have breakpoint at the very beginning of this event handler but when I press the button I never got to this method, instead in `Site.Master.cs` :

```
        protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Set Anti-XSRF token
                ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
                ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                // Validate the Anti-XSRF token
                if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                    || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed.");
                }
            }
        }
```

I got an error from inside the above method - **`Validation of Anti-XSRF token failed`**

The things that confuses me is that - I suspect, the I didn't got this error at the beginning, second, this code is as trivial as it can be, nothing that I haven't add to my code, just the more basic - `button - event handler` set up you can get.

P.S

this is at the top of my `.aspx` page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 

CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebFormsApp.Clients.Default" %>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and inspecting the values you are comparing? You are not assigning _antiXsrfTokenValue anywhere in the code you posted so your assignment code does not match your comparison code.

Comment: @BenRobinson yeah, I'm not assigning it. At least for me the confusing part is that I just add a button and a handler - I would expect that the framework would take care for this itself. Also I'm pretty sure I didn't get this error from the beginning. However, how can I explicitly assign the `_antiXsrfTokenValue` so I I pass the check. As it seems the error is in this check `(string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue`